# How to declare handle array

Tags: arrays, matlab, handle

When using cycles for populating arrays in MATLAB the code analyser throws warnings `The variable 'foo' changes appears to change size on every loop iteration. Consider preallocating for speed.`

Typical case:

```
for ii=1:3
  foo(ii)=rand;
  bar{ii}=rand;
end
```

this can be solved easily by preallocating, obviously.

```
foo=nan(3,1);bar=cell(3,1);
for ii=1:3
  foo(ii)=rand;
  bar{ii}=rand;
end
```

The problem is when I am not populating numeric or cell arrays but handle arrays, typically a set of lines to be accessible from different parts of code.

I have found one walkaround - loop backwards:

```
for ii=3:-1:1
  foo(ii)=line(nan,nan);
end
```

But is there more neat way how to get rid of the warning, besides `%#ok<*NASGU>` or `%#ok<NASGU>` comments?

Comment: You can use [`gobjects`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gobjects.html).  [`empty`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html) methods are another option.

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate on the `empty` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating line objects, there is specifically a workaround for that which avoids a loop altogether. You can pass a matrix of values to [`line`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) to create one line per column. For example, this creates 3 line objects and stores the handles in a 3-by-1 vector:

```
h = line(nan(2, 3), nan(2, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `gobjects` is designed for just this purpose - it will return you a preallocated array of `matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder` objects with a size that you specify. You can then fill the array with graphics objects such as lines.

Note that you can usefully test elements of that array with `isgraphics` - elements that are actual graphics handles will return `true`, whereas elements that are `GraphicsPlaceholder` will return `false`.

If you're specifically looking to just turn off the warning, then `%#ok` comments are the right way to do it. You can turn off the warning globally in your Preferences, which will mean you can omit the `%#ok` comment, but that will mean that you miss the warning for all preallocations, not just for arrays of graphics handles.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store the handles in a `double` array:

```
foo = zeros(3,1);
for ii=1:3
  foo(ii)=double(line(nan,nan));
end
```

You can convert them back to handles using the `handle()` method. But you don't need to do it explicitly most of the time. You can use the `get` and `set` functions with the numeric representation directly.